# Cursor in T-SQL doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, ssms-2014

I am using cursor to randomly copy data from one table(Family_tree) to two other tables(Family_tree1 + @time, Family_tree2 + @time). Code executes successfully, but no row is updated. There IS actually what to copy from a table.
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Here's the part of script with cursor:

```
---creating two tables beforehand
DECLARE @random int
DECLARE 
@first_name nvarchar(20),
@last_name AS nvarchar(20),
@date_of_birth AS nchar(10),
@date_of_death AS nchar(10),
@place_of_death AS nvarchar(30),
@credit_card AS nchar(16),
@ID_member AS int,
@FK_gender AS nchar(3), 

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, date_of_death, place_of_death, credit_card, ID_member, FK_gender,  FROM Family_tree
OPEN curs

FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO  @first_name, @last_name, @date_of_birth, @date_of_death, @place_of_death, @credit_card, @ID_member, @FK_gender, 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @random = RAND() * 1000000
    IF @random % 2 = 1
    BEGIN 
        SET @sqlString = 'INSERT INTO [Family_tree1' + @time +  ']  (first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, date_of_death, place_of_death,  credit_card, ID_member, FK_gender) 
    VALUES (' 
     + @first_name  + ','  + @last_name  + ',' + @date_of_birth + ',' + @date_of_death + ',' + @place_of_death + ',' + @credit_card + ',' 
     + CAST(@ID_member AS nvarchar)  +','+ @FK_gender  + ')'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    SET @sqlString = 'INSERT INTO [Family_tree2' + @time +  '] (first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, date_of_death, place_of_death, credit_card, ID_member, FK_gender) 
    VALUES (' + @first_name  + ','  + @last_name  + ',' + @date_of_birth + ',' + @date_of_death + ',' + @place_of_death + ',' + @credit_card + ',' 
     + CAST(@ID_member AS nvarchar)  +','+ @FK_gender + ')'
END
EXECUTE(@sqlString)
FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO  @first_name, @last_name, @date_of_birth, @date_of_death, @place_of_death, @credit_card, @ID_member, @FK_gender
END
CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
END;
```

I am new to T-SQL and will appreciate any advice!
Thank You in advance (:

Comment: Why you require cursor for this? What is your input and what is you expecting?

Comment: Copying data from one table to another is something **easily** done without cursors.

Comment: And the reason this is failing is almost certainly one or more of those variables you're building a string from contains a `NULL` and `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` so the whole string becomes `NULL`.

Comment: Why make a new table with a timestamp in the name? Why not just add a datetime column to a table and keep the data in the same table?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy 
I have to use cursor because that is what my task requires. In the table Family_tree some fields actually contain NULLs and I need that NULLs. How can I concat that string if I can't take away those nulls?

Comment: suppose field1 can be null, than just do isnull(field1, '') and now the null will be replaced by an empty string

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank You for response!
Perhaps You are right about that string concatenation.
But how can I concat that string if I can't take away those nulls?
What is the best way to do that?

Comment: @GuidoG , thanks, I'll try that now (:

Comment: do you mean you have to use a cursor because someone told you so ? If that is the case than this person has little knowledge of sql and you should not learn anything from him

Comment: "That's what my task requires" sounds like a homework assignment or something you should challenge to whoever told you to do that.

Comment: @JacobH it IS a homework assignment :D
That is why I am using cursors and tables with a timestamp in the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "have" to do it in the cursor, then you need to watch out for nulls. You also need to watch out for the fact that you're using strings and these should be *quoted* when inserted into a `VALUES` clause.

Instead of

```
VALUES (' + @first_name  + ',
```

You need something like:

```
VALUES (' + COALESCE('''' + REPLACE(@first_name,'''','''''') + '''','NULL')  + ',
```

And so on for the rest of your values. This replaces any single quotes within the value with doubled-up quotes, then wraps the whole string in single quotes. `NULL`s survive through all of that processing so we then also use `COALESCE` to replace the `NULL` with a `NULL` literal in the eventual string<sup>1</sup>.

Before running the cursor in anger, I'd suggest you do this for one row and print the string rather than executing it, to check that it "looks right".

I'd also suggest you look into using better data types - dates of birth/death would be much better dealt with as actual `date` values rather than strings.

---

<sup>1</sup>Guido suggested `ISNULL` in the comments, which is similar to `COALESCE` but has some odd limitations and I'd usually recommend against using. They also suggested that the replacement should be an empty string, but here that would result in `VALUES(... ,, ...)` at the position of the `NULL` value which would generate an error.

Comment: Thank You for such explicit advices! Now everything works properly.